# Get all occurences between characters to get same result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I'm looking inside string `3-431 a4-2 4-13` and want to find `3-431`, `a4-2` and `4-13`. I use the following pattern:

```
/(.*-.* )*/gU
```

and I get the desired result without a problem: [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA5eS5/1)

The question is - how to achieve same result when I want to look inside string that start and ends with some other substrings for example `[` and `]`.

If I modify subject to `[3-431 a4-2 4-13 ]` and regex to `/\[(.*-.* )*\]/gU` I'm getting only the last occurence: `4-13` and I'm not getting same results as in 1st example. [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA5eS5/2)

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use split with ` ` ?

Comment: [You can use `/\w+-\w+/` for matching](https://regex101.com/r/wG7uS3/1)

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with a single regex. In PCRE, quantified capture groups get overwritten each quantified pass, leaving only the last value in the group. I would recommend using the `\G` construct but this involves a redundant (expensive) lookahead on each match.

Comment: The trivial way is to capture the contents `\[([^\]]+)\]` then parse group 1 for the values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regex you can use `explode` or split by space:

```
$str  = "3-431 a4-2 4-13";
$parts = explode(" ", $str);
echo $parts [0]; // 3-431
echo $parts [1]; // a4-2
echo $parts [2]; // 4-13
```

However, if you still want to use a regex, then you can use:

```
$re = "/(\\w+-\\w+)/"; 
$str = "3-431 a4-2 4-13"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR2jA9/1)**

Btw, if your string is always separated by spaces, then you can also use this regex:

```
$re = "/(\\S+)/"; 
$str = "3-431 a4-2 4-13"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR2jA9/2)**

On the other hand, if your string starts and ends with `[` and `]`, as `[3-431 a4-2 4-13 ]`. The idea is to leverage the **discard technique**, you could use this regex:

```
[[\]](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\S+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR2jA9/3)**

And also, getting the same result using `preg_split` for above string:

```
$exploded = preg_split('[[\]\s]+', '[3-431 a4-2 4-13]', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `.+` and not `.*` since `+` means at least once. Then your regex is:

```
/\[(\w+-\w+)*\s*\]/sgU
```

Comment: You must indent code (and regexes) 4 spaces otherwise things will get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted to do regex this will work:

```
(^|\])[^[]*\[([^[]*-[^[]* )*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(.*-.* )+
```

Basically, if the occurrence happens outside of `[` and `]` it will fail.

---

The reason that your were only getting one match is that the global modifier will only match another occurrence after the first match ends, which in your case was after the closing brace.